# How to modify specific attribute of a vertex in compute shader

Tags: c, opengl, glsl

I have a buffer containing `6` values, the first three being position and the other three are the color of the vertex. I want to modify those values in the compute shader, but only positions, not the color. I achieved this by using Image Load/Store, but I used all vertex data, not only a part of it (one attribute). So basically I don't know how to get only one attribute in compute shader, and modify it, and write it back to the buffer.

---

**This is the code that worked for one (and only) attribute.**

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, NULL);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

glGenTextures(1, &position_tbo);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, position_tbo);
glTexBuffer(GL_TEXTURE_BUFFER, GL_RGBA32F, position_buffer);
```

---

**glsl:**

```
layout (local_size_x = 128) in;

layout (rgba32f, binding = 0) uniform imageBuffer position_buffer;

void main(void)
{
    vec4 pos = imageLoad(position_buffer, int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x));

    pos.xyz = (translation * vec4(pos.xyz, 1.0)).xyz;

    imageStore(position_buffer, int(gl_GlobalInvocationID.x), pos);
}
```

So how do I store only part of the vertex data into `pos`, not all attributes? Where do I specify what attribute goes into `pos`? And if I `imageStore` some specific attribute back to the buffer, am I sure that only that part of the buffer will be changed (the attribute I want to modify) and other attributes will remain the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertex Array State defined by functions like `glVertexAttribPointer()` is only relevant when drawing with the graphics pipeline. It defines the mapping from buffer elements to input vertex attributes. It does not have any effect in compute mode.

It is you yourself who defines the layout of your vertex buffer(s) and sets up the Vertex Array accordingly. Thus, you necessarily know where in your buffer to find which component of which attribute. If you didn't then you couldn't ever use the buffer to draw anything either.

I'm not sure why exactly you chose to use image load/store to access your vertex data in your compute shader. I would suggest simply binding it as a [shader storage buffer](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object). Assuming your buffers just contain a bunch of floats, the probably simplest approach would be to just interpret them as an array of floats in your compute shader:

```
layout(std430, binding = 0) buffer VertexBuffer
{
    float vertex_data[];
};
```

You can then just access the i-th float in your buffer as `vertex_data[i]` in your compute shader via a normal index, just like any other array…

Apart from all that, I should point out that the `glVertexAttribPointer()` call in your code above sets up the buffer for only one vertex attribute consisting of 4 floats rather than two attributes of 3 floats each.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't have experience with shader storage buffer, but I will try if I don't succeed with the current approach.

Comment: Although, I know the exact structure of the buffer, it goes three by three floats : `x,y,z` and then `r,g,b`. Is there a way to access only `x,y,z` parts, modify them, and store them back to the buffer, using image loading and `imageBuffer` as I did in above example? The problem is that `imageLoad` returns only `vec4`.

Comment: Yes, as written in my comment to the other answer: using an `rgb32f` image should do the trick I think. Image loads/stores just work on entire elements. If you want your elements to just have three components, you have to use an element format with just three components. However, I'm not sure why exactly you would use image load/store to access a buffer like this. Is there any specific reason? It seems unnecessarily complicated to me…

Comment: Not some specific reason, I just saw this approach in the OpenGL Red Book. I will try the storage buffer now.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel: There is no rgb32f image format. Image texture can only consist of 1, 2 or 4 channels.

Comment: @BDL indeed, I must have misread that in the spec. Then there's no simple way to achieve what he wants to achieve with image load/store at all.

Comment: Just one more question. In your example of storage buffer, is `vertex_data[]` the whole buffer, or some part of it? Do I need to check the workgroups to know where in the buffer I am, or I can just iterate through the whole buffer from start to finish inside of 'vertex_data[]' ?

Comment: What `vertex_data[]` becomes depends on how you bind your buffer to it. If you bind the whole buffer (e.g. with `glBindBufferBase()`), then it will be the whole buffer. You can get the length of the array via `vertex_data.length()`. I'm not sure what you mean by "iterate from start to finish inside of 'vertex_data[]'".